# Laravel 5.6 Nested Querying Relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship

Hi guys I need to query a deep relationship...

My `store` Model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Store extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'stores';

    public function address(){

        return $this->morphOne('App\Model\Address', 'addressable');
    }

}
```

My `Address` Model

```php
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'address';
    protected $fillable = [
        'province_id',
        'city_id',
        'brgy_id',
        'street_lot_blk',
        'longitude',
        'latitude'
    ];

    public function addressable(){

         return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function province(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Province', 'id', 'province_id');
    }

    public function city(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\City', 'id', 'city_id');
    }

     public function brgy(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Brgy', 'id', 'brgy_id');
    }
}
```

My `province` Model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Province extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'refprovince';
}
```

My Query

```php
$request = app()->make('request');

        return response()->json([
                'stores' => Store::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->name . '%')
                    ->with(['address.province', 'address.city', 'address.brgy'])
                    ->take(10)->get()
            ]);
```

The `result`  see attached photo

[image]

The problem is If the user type the name of the store it would only return the name of the store and if the user type "Camarines" it would only return the Store who have a "Camarines" word in the province.

My code looks like this... but it doesn't work.

```php
 $results = Store::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->name . '%')
                    ->with(['address.province' => function($query) use ($request) {

                        $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->name . '%');

                    }])
                    ->take(10)->get();

        return response()->json([
                'stores' => $results
            ]);
```

I don't know if this one is possible just tell me so that I can re structure my database. TY

Updates: Still it doesn't work with these code.

```php
$request = app()->make('request');

         $stores = Store::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%")
        ->orWhereHas('address.province', function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%");
        })
        ->with(['address.province', 'address.city', 'address.brgy'])
        ->get();
```

[image]

Comment: So you want the stores where the name matches OR where the provDesc matches?

Comment: Yeah... but It doesn't work. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `with()` doesn't constrain or add conditions to a query. It only tells Laravel which relationships to load later (in a separate query) after the first query is run. The callback you pass is constraining the models loaded during the secondary query, but not while deciding which Stores to retrieve.

It currently reads like this:

- Load the first (up to) 10 stores where name is like %name%

  - Load the address for each of those (up to) 10 IDs returned (running a whereIn() query on the IDs)

    - Load the province for each of those addresses, but only if `provDesc` was LIKE %name% (again with a whereIn() query on the IDs of addresses)

Solution: *add* `orWhereHas()` to the Store's query:

```
Store::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$foo%")

    ->orWhereHas('address.province', function ($query) {
        $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', "%$foo%");
    });
```

But still using `with()` to include the relationships you'll want to use:

```
$stores = Store::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%")
    ->orWhereHas('address.province', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%");
    })
    ->with('address.province')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Or if you wanted the address's province relationship eager loaded *only when it matched* %name%:

```
$stores = Store::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%")
    ->orWhereHas('address.province', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%");
    })
    ->with(['address.province' => function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', "%{$request->name}%");
    }])
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Comment: @Rbex do the stores *always* need to load the province relationship with the address, or is it just for finding the right stores?

Comment: no... it should be orWhere but I'm fine with that... I can change it. Both of it should use orWhere... the store and the province. How about `address.city` I will add it inside the `with` also?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted `address.city` eager loaded as well you can include it: `with('address.city', 'address.province')` or `with(['address.city', 'address.province'])`

Comment: Still it doesn't work... maybe because of polymorphic relationship?

Comment: @Rbex what doesn't work now? I thought you said it worked like a charm?

Comment: I update the questions... I thought also it works but after checking with my team. It doesn't work. It displays all eventhough there is a match of "provDesc"

Comment: as you can see, the search string is "ceb" but it displays all of it...

Comment: You can use teamviewer, if its not too much for you.

Comment: Your request parameter is called `search` (`?search=ceb`), but your code is using `name`. Try `$request->search` instead, and validate that it's not null (which will return all matches if you're checking `LIKE %%` - which is what it's probably doing right now. Meaning, $request->name is probably empty causing everything to be returned.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry... I'm not anymore in my mind. Thanks... now it really works.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. You need to have an `OR` clause to search for records where one or the other condition is true (the store name matches the search OR the province provDesc matches the search). You can use `orWhere()` to add an `OR` clause to the query.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

2. The stores are your main results here, and the provinces are related records. The `with()` method will not filter the main results, it will only filter the related models that are returned WITH the main results. To filter main results by a query on related records, use `whereHas()` (or `orWhereHas()`, `whereDoesntHave()`, etc.).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Try something like this:

```
$results = Store::whereHas('province', function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('provDesc', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->name . '%');
})->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->name . '%');
```

Comment: it doesn't work... I tried it. Maybe because of polymorphic relationship or the eager loading `with()`?